# e.printStackTrace(); is not printing in app-engine console

Tags: google-app-engine

I am not seeing any stack trace printed from e.printStackTrace(); in my java app-engine console running on google box(not local one). I have tried log level ALL, DEBUG and INFO in logging.properties file. Still no stack trace. I  only see my logging print from _logger statement. It's not helping much to trace the bug. How can I get stack trace printed?

```
    { ....
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        _logger.severe("Exception : " + e);
    }
```

Comment: I have the same problem. The documentation about logging is very that it should be in the log, but it doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.
Try

_logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(),e);

instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't give `printStackTrace()` an argument, it will print to the standard error stream. This error output stream will be the value of `System.err`.

Comment: `Everything the servlet writes to the standard output stream (System.out) and standard error stream (System.err) is captured by App Engine and recorded in the application logs. Lines written to the standard output stream are logged at the "INFO" level, and lines written to the standard error stream are logged at the "WARNING" level.` so they should be in the console. Why don't I see the stack trace then?